# Обосновано ли здесь применение вложенной функции?

Tags: python, функции, beautiful-soup

Вот у меня есть функция-парсер сайта. Во время парсинга я ищу все теги, у которых нету атрибута class. То есть надо создать функцию-фильтр, которая будет определять, есть ли у тега атрибут class. Вот эту функцию-фильтр я где должен определить? В локальной или глобальной области видимости? Эту функцию-фильтр я нигде в глобальной области видимости применять не буду, и импортировать ее в другие модули тоже не собираюсь.

```
def parser(url):
    def tag_filer(tag):
        return not (tag.has_attr('class'))
    # тут создается BeautifulSoup для url. Затем к нему применяется метод soup.find_all(tag_filer)
```

Comment: Передавайте лямбду вместо `tag_filer`. Вот так: `soup.find_all(lambda tag: not tag.has_attr('class'))`

Comment: А если предположить, что фильтрация более сложная. В таком случае лямбды не хватит

Comment: В таком случае вложенная функция будет лучше, если этот фильтр вам не нужен в других местах. Думаю так, но совсем уверен

Comment: В PEP 8 ничего об этом не нашёл.. Но если ожидается, что `tag_filer` будет достаточно длинной, лучше, мне кажется,  вынести её отдельно. Не стоит делать тело внешней функции слишком большим. И если внутренняя функция занимает существенную часть этого тела, то, может, она уже самодостаточна, чтобы определяться независимо. Исходите из удобства чтения кода.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответы. Мне понравилось "исходите из удобства чтения кода". Запомню, буду применять